# condition in foreach xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xslt and we are using xslt 1.0 for xml transformation.
I have a source xml,in which an element PID11 is repeating. PID11 has child element XAD.7. The values XAD.7 can be 'Home','Business','Alternate' etc. but each of them will be one time. PID11 can repeat multiple times.Our requirement is first check for XAD.7 as 'Home' .if XAD.7 as 'Home',just copy the child nodes to target.If XAD.7 as 'Home' is not found in any of the child,check for XAD.7 as 'Business'.and if 'Business' is found just copy the child nodes and so on.

Below is the Source xml

```
 <ADT_A01 xmlns="http://www.edifecs.com/xdata/200"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         XDataVersion="2.0" Standard="HL7" Version="2.3"
         CreatedDate="2016-08-25T23:58:43" CreatedBy="XEngine_3000"
         GUID="{855FB5C6-6B5A-11E6-9457-005056BC4156}">
   <Internal-Properties>
      <Data-Structure Name="Message">
         <Lookup Name="InternatCodeAlternateID"/>
         <Lookup Name="InternatCodeAlternateSystem"/>
         &gt;
      </Data-Structure>
   </Internal-Properties>
   <MSH>
      <MSH.1>|</MSH.1>
      <MSH.2>^~\&amp;</MSH.2>
         </MSH>
   <PID>
      <PID.1>1</PID.1>
      <PID.2 xsi:nil="true"/>
        <PID.11>
         <XAD.1>531 Business 11TH ST</XAD.1>
         <XAD.2 xsi:nil="true"/>
         <XAD.3 xsi:nil="true"/>
         <XAD.4>CA</XAD.4>
         <XAD.5 xsi:nil="true"/>
         <XAD.6 xsi:nil="true"/>
         <XAD.7>Business</XAD.7>
      </PID.11>
      <PID.11>
         <XAD.1>531 Home 11TH ST</XAD.1>
         <XAD.2 xsi:nil="true"/>
         <XAD.3>LONG BEACH</XAD.3>
         <XAD.4>CA</XAD.4>
         <XAD.5>90813</XAD.5>
         <XAD.6>USA</XAD.6>
         <XAD.7>Home</XAD.7>
         <XAD.8 xsi:nil="true"/>
         <XAD.9>Los Angeles</XAD.9>
      </PID.11>

      <PID.12 xsi:nil="true"/>
      <PID.13>
         <XTN.1>(562)495-1306</XTN.1>
      </PID.13>
      <PID.14>
         <XTN.1>5627194222</XTN.1>
      </PID.14>
      <PID.15>
         <CE_0296.1>SP</CE_0296.1>
      </PID.15>
   </PID>
   <PV1>
      <PV1.1>1</PV1.1>
      <PV1.2>I</PV1.2>
      <PV1.3>
         <PL.1>5U</PL.1>
         <PL.2>00</PL.2>
         <PL.3>7</PL.3>
         <PL.4>
            <HD.1>HAR</HD.1>
         </PL.4>
      </PV1.3>
      <PV1.4>1</PV1.4>
      <PV1.5 xsi:nil="true"/>
      <PV1.6 xsi:nil="true"/>
   </PV1>
</ADT_A01>
```

---

Expected xml output:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<top:AdtLevel1SegmentsCollection xmlns:bpmn="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpm/xpath" xmlns:top="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/top/Insert_HL7_ADT_A01_Staging">
   <top:AdtLevel1Segments>
      <top:msh10MsgCntrlId>Q10139555T12193933X316716</top:msh10MsgCntrlId>
      <top:msh4Sendfac>HUMC_EGATE</top:msh4Sendfac>
      <top:msh7MsgTsDt/>
      <top:pid3InpidCx1Id>100004465</top:pid3InpidCx1Id>
      <top:pid18Cx1Paccntno/>
      <top:pv119_Cx1Visitnumb/>
      <top:msh1FieldSeparator>|</top:msh1FieldSeparator>
      <top:msh2EncodingCharacters>^~\&amp;</top:msh2EncodingCharacters>
      <top:msh3Sendapp>
         CERNER
      </top:msh3Sendapp>
      <top:msh5Recapp>
         AFFINITY
      </top:msh5Recapp>
      <top:msh6Recfac>
         HAR
      </top:msh6Recfac>
      <top:msh8Security/>
      <top:msh9CmMsg1Msgid/>
      <top:msh9CmMsg2Trigevent/>
      <top:msh11Pt1ProcId>P</top:msh11Pt1ProcId>
      <top:msh11Pt2ProcMode/>
      <top:msh12VersionId>2.3</top:msh12VersionId>
      <top:msh13SeqNumber/>
      <top:msh14ContPointer/>
      <top:msh15AcceptAckType/>
      <top:evn1EventTypecode/>
      <top:evn2Ts1RecordedDatetime/>
      <top:evn2Ts2RecordedDatetime/>
      <top:evn5Cn1Operidcd/>
      <top:evn5Cn2Namelast/>
      <top:evn5Cn3Namefirst/>
      <top:evn5Cn4Namemidd/>
      <top:evn5Cn5Namesuff/>
      <top:evn5Cn6Namepref/>
      <top:evn6Ts1EventOccured/>
      <top:evn6Ts2EventOccured/>
      <top:drg1_Ce1DiagReltdIdntfr/>
      <top:drg1_Ce2DiagTxt/>
      <top:drg2_Ts1DiagAssignDt/>
      <top:drg2_Ts2DiagAssignTm/>
      <top:drg3_DiagApprvlInd/>
      <top:drg4_DiagGrpReviewCd/>
      <top:drg5_Ce1OutReimTypIdnt/>
      <top:ub11_SetId/>
      <top:ub12_BloodDeductible/>
      <top:ub21_SetId/>
      <top:ub22_CoInsDays/>
      <top:ub23_ConditionCd/>
      <top:z011_Intpatientid/>
      <top:z012_Medicaidid/>
      <top:z013_Gendercode/>
      <top:z014_Dob/>
      <top:z101_Patientaccno/>
      <top:z102_Lstspuncldaccno/>
      <top:z103_Pcatcode/>
      <top:insertDt>2016-11-04T21:10:54.966+05:30</top:insertDt>
      <top:messageType>ADT_A01Hist</top:messageType>
      <top:processedFlag>H</top:processedFlag>
      <top:adtLevel1Pid>
         <top:pid1SetidPatientid>1</top:pid1SetidPatientid>
         <top:pid2ExpidCx1Id/>
         <top:pid4AlpidCx1Id/>
         <top:pid5Xpn1PnameLast/>
         <top:pid5Xpn2PnameFirst/>
         <top:pid5Xpn3PnameMidd/>
         <top:pid6Xpn1PmothmnameLast/>
         <top:pid6Xpn2PmothmnameFirst/>
         <top:pid6Xpn3PmothmnameMidd/>
         <top:pid7Ts1Pdateofbirth>19470409</top:pid7Ts1Pdateofbirth>
         <top:pid7Ts2Ptimeofbirth/>
         <top:pid8Psexcode>F</top:pid8Psexcode>
         <top:pid9Xpn1PalianameLast/>
         <top:pid9Xpn2PalianameFirst/>
         <top:pid9Xpn3PalianameMidd/>
         <top:pid11Xad1Straddr1>531 Home 11TH ST</top:pid11Xad1Straddr1>
          <top:pid12Countycd/>
         <top:pid13Xtn1Pathomephnnn>(562)495-1306</top:pid13Xtn1Pathomephnnn>
         <top:pid13Xtn2Telecomusecd/>
         <top:pid14Xtn1Patbusphnnn>5627194222</top:pid14Xtn1Patbusphnnn>
         <top:pid14Xtn2Telecomusecd/>
         <top:pid15Ce1Primlangcd>SP</top:pid15Ce1Primlangcd>
         <top:pid16Maritalcode/>
         <top:pid17Religion/>
         <top:pid19Ssn/>
         <top:pid20Dln1Dln/>
         <top:pid20Dln2Issuedt/>
         <top:pid20Dln3Expdt/>
         <top:pid21Cx1Mothid/>
         <top:pid22Pethcd/>
         <top:pid23Pbirthplace/>
         <top:pid24Pmultbirthind/>
         <top:pd11_LivDep/>
         <top:pd12_LivArr/>
         <top:pd13_Xon1Orgname/>
         <top:pd13_Xon2Nametype/>
         <top:pd14_Xcn1Id/>
         <top:pd14_Xcn2Namelast/>
         <top:pd14_Xcn3Namefirst/>
         <top:pd14_Xcn4Namemidd/>
         <top:pd15_Stndcd/>
         <top:pd16_Handicap/>
         <top:pd17_LivingWillCd/>
         <top:pd18_OrganDonorCd/>
         <top:pd19_Separatbill/>
         <top:pd110_Cx1Duppat/>
         <top:pd111_Ce1Pubindcd/>
         <top:pd112_Protind/>
         <top:zpi1Setid/>
         <top:zpi2Ptempaddr/>
         <top:zpi3Presdt/>
         <top:zpi4Pbrthplace/>
         <top:zei1Setid/>
         <top:zei2Emplsttscd/>
         <top:zei3EmplnameFt/>
         <top:insertDt>2016-11-04T21:10:54.967+05:30</top:insertDt>
         <top:messageType>ADT_A01Hist</top:messageType>
         <top:processedFlag>H</top:processedFlag>
         <top:adtLevel2PidRaceCollection>
            <top:AdtLevel2PidRace>
               <top:pid10PatientRace>1</top:pid10PatientRace>
               <top:insertDt>2016-11-04T21:10:54.967+05:30</top:insertDt>
               <top:messageType>ADT_A01Hist</top:messageType>
               <top:processedFlag>H</top:processedFlag>
            </top:AdtLevel2PidRace>
            <top:AdtLevel2PidRace>
               <top:pid10PatientRace>""</top:pid10PatientRace>
               <top:insertDt>2016-11-04T21:10:54.967+05:30</top:insertDt>
               <top:messageType>ADT_A01Hist</top:messageType>
               <top:processedFlag>H</top:processedFlag>
            </top:AdtLevel2PidRace>
         </top:adtLevel2PidRaceCollection>
      </top:adtLevel1Pid>
      <top:adtLevel1Pv1>
         <top:pv11_Setid>1</top:pv11_Setid>
         <top:pv12_Pclass>I</top:pv12_Pclass>
         <top:pv13_Pl1AssgplocPoc>5U</top:pv13_Pl1AssgplocPoc>
         <top:pv13_Pl2AssgplocRoom>00</top:pv13_Pl2AssgplocRoom>
         <top:pv13_Pl3AssgplocBed>7</top:pv13_Pl3AssgplocBed>
         <top:pv13_Pl4AssgplocFac>
            HAR
         </top:pv13_Pl4AssgplocFac>
         <top:pv14_Admtype>1</top:pv14_Admtype>
         <top:pv16_Pl1PplocPoc/>
         <top:pv16_Pl2PplocRoom/>
         <top:pv16_Pl3PplocBed/>
         <top:pv16_Pl4PplocFac/>
         <top:pv17_Xcn1Attenddoctid/>
         <top:pv17_Xcn2Namelast/>
         <top:pv17_Xcn3Namefirst/>
         <top:pv17_Xcn4Namemidd/>
         <top:pv19_Xcn1Consdoctid/>
         <top:pv19_Xcn2Namelast/>
         <top:pv19_Xcn3Namefirst/>
         <top:pv19_Xcn4Namemidd/>
         <top:pv110_HospitalService/>
         <top:pv114_Admitsrccd/>
         <top:pv117_Xcn1Admitdoctid/>
         <top:pv117_Xcn2Namelast/>
         <top:pv117_Xcn3Namefirst/>
         <top:pv117_Xcn4Namemidd/>
         <top:pv118_Ptype/>
         <top:pv120_Fc1Finclass/>
         <top:pv120_Fc2Effdt/>
         <top:pv136_Dischargaccntdisp/>
         <top:pv141_Accntstatus/>
         <top:pv144_AdmtdtTs1/>
         <top:pv144_AdmtdtTs2/>
         <top:pv145_DischdtTs1/>
         <top:pv145_DischdtTs2/>
         <top:pv21_Pl1PrplocPoc/>
         <top:pv21_Pl2PrplocRoom/>
         <top:pv21_Pl3PrplocBed/>
         <top:pv21_Pl4PrplocFac/>
         <top:pv21_Pl5PrplocBedsta/>
         <top:pv21_Pl6PrplocLoctype/>
         <top:pv21_Pl7PrplocBuild/>
         <top:pv21_Pl8PrplocFloor/>
         <top:pv21_Pl9PrplocLocdesc/>
         <top:pv23_Ce1Admitreasoncd/>
         <top:pv24_Ce1Trreasoncd/>
         <top:zvi1TraumaCd/>
         <top:zvi2TraumaDtTm/>
         <top:zvi3LastTraumaDtTm/>
         <top:zvi4ReferringComment/>
         <top:zvi5ChartLocation/>
         <top:insertDt>2016-11-04T21:10:54.968+05:30</top:insertDt>
         <top:messageType>ADT_A01Hist</top:messageType>
         <top:processedFlag>H</top:processedFlag>
      </top:adtLevel1Pv1>

   </top:AdtLevel1Segments>
</top:AdtLevel1SegmentsCollection>
```

I am not able to put my xslt here as it is goes beyond the character limit.

I just want to iterate all instances of repeating PID11 and check if XAD.7 as Home exists,it can ignore other instance of PID11 and copy the instance which has XAD.7 as Home to the target.if in any of the PID11 instance XAD.7 as Home doesn't exist,then check for XAD.7 as Business.If XAD.7 as Business is found,ignore other instance of PID11 and just copy the instance which has XAD.7 as Business to the target

Can you please help in xslt writing.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.Please let me know if I should give a short xml

Comment: It might help if you did simplify your output XML to only focus on the part you are stuck on. At the moment, your output XML contains a large number of (empty) elements which may be needed for your application, but are not relevant to that actual problem in hand. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some useful advice on structuring your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to exactly what you're after, but if all you want to do is process 'home' entries followed by 'business' entries could you do something like this?

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="PID.11[XAD.7='Home']/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="PID.11[XAD.7='Business']/>
```

Alternatively (if a select will not easily capture all of the elements in your input document), you could use a 'Home' and 'Business' mode.